# Find projects that use a particular programming language in Launchpad?

Tags: development, launchpad, search, vala

On [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/), most projects list the programming language(s) their software uses:

[image]

It would be useful if there was a way to get a list of all the projects that use "X" programming language, in my case [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala). Does Launchpad provide this functionality? Are there any 3rd party tools that can do this?

Comment: Good question. I'm curious to know if there is an answer to this.

Comment: have you seen this https://launchpad.net/vala

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Marco Ceppi has pointed me towards `launchpadlib`, I wrote a little script that will do this for you. **[[image] download it here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/540827/)**

Run the script by calling `python name_of_the_script.py` in a Terminal after you've downloaded and saved it. It will ask you for a programming language, case insensitive, and a search query (where wildcards, `*`, are allowed). If you leave either of them blank, it will search across all, rather than none.

You'll need to install `python-launchpadlib` before you can use it.

Here's some example output:

```
stefano@3000-G530:~$ python test.py 
Enter a programming language or leave blank to find projects in all languages:
>>> Python
Enter a search query or leave blank for all:
>>> Calculator
calcool - A document based calculator tool...
evias - Web site used to apply Eve DB dump to Eve API results and get th...
txevolver - txEvolver is a Twisted-based set of libraries for performing ...
[...]
```

Comment: Not the best code I ever wrote though... But it works fine.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but: Thanks for making me aware of this library :P

Comment: Would it be possible to paste the python script directly into the answer. The paste is no longer available. Side note: see this question for this issue: [Does pastes made on Ubuntu Pastebin Service get deleted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/288083/does-pastes-made-on-ubuntu-pastebin-service-get-deleted)

Comment: I'll second that.  I'd really like to see a way of searching launchpadlib using wildcards and the pastebin no longer exists...

Answer (score 7):

Launchpad doesn't have this functionality. The request for it is [bug #2630](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad-registry/+bug/2630), which you may want to subscribe to.

Answer (score 1):

You can find particular project in the following link.But as far as i know you can not list projects that uses X programming langauge.

https://launchpad.net/projects

[image]