# Do pastes made on Ubuntu Pastebin Service get deleted?

Tags: pastebin

I had used [Ubuntu's Pastebin Service](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) to give the output of terminal commands as follow-up for the following question I had asked:

- [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages)

However, now I am not able to access any of the pastes I had made. There are atleast 5 pastebin links if I am counting correctly. All the links complain as:

> The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist.

See the image for yourself:

[image: Ubuntu Pastebin - paste doesn't exist]

So, is there any condition that the pastes would be deleted:

- after x number of days, or
- if it doesn't get atleast x number of views every y days, or
- something similar.

Is it possible to recover them in any manner?

Comment: I think it ought to be deleted after 30 days but that never happened until recently. Now I see so many broken links.

Comment: @jokerdino: The service doesn't mention anywhere that the pastes would get deleted after 30 days. Had that been the case, I would never have used the service altogether.

Answer (score 9):

It took 8 years for Pastebin.com to surpass 10 million "Active" pastes (not spam or expired pastes).[1](http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/26/pastebin-surpasses-10-million-active-pastes/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20Techcrunch%20%28TechCrunch%29) Less than a year later the owners of Pastebin.com tweeted that they had already surpassed the 20 million active pastes mark.<sup>[Tech Crunch](http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/26/pastebin-surpasses-10-million-active-pastes/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20Techcrunch%20%28TechCrunch%29)</sup>

The maximum size a paste can be is 512 kilobytes (0.5 megabytes). This should be enough for almost any script, and it prevents people from jamming our servers. PRO members are allowed to create pastes up to 10 megabytes.

[image]

As far as pastebin.ubuntu.com, from what I found out from my pastes that it's probably a six to nine month windows.  Because anything that I pasted that's less that nine months old, I can still find, but anything over a year I'm not able to find.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

I found some information here → https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pastebinit/+question/127981
that lead me to this screenshot of the first post on Ubuntu pastbin and it is still there... "Notice the Date"

[image]

My guess is a "bad" or "mistyped" link maybe...

Comment: I use pastebin.ubuntu.com form 2008, this cannot be the first post.